# Entrypoint script is not running from docker-compose file

Tags: sql, shell, asp.net-core, docker-compose, sqlcmd

My goal is to create an SQL login for my apps before running other images. Since my container uses Linux - scripts are saved with LF line endings. And the Docker output console is not showing any errors related to the script, only about my apps - they can't connect to the server because no such login exists.

The problem is that the shell script is not running and no login is being created. Thanks for your help in advance.

I was looking for the examples on the web, and here is what I came up with:

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    mssql:
        image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
        environment:
            SA_PASSWORD: "3qqimIuTQEGqVCD!"
            ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
            LOGIN: "MyLogin"
            PASSWORD: "3qqimIuTQEGqVCD!"

        ports:
            - "1433:1433"
        volumes:
            - ./DockerScripts/SQL/CreateLogin.sql:/CreateLogin.sql
            - ./DockerScripts/Shell/Entrypoint.sh:/Entrypoint.sh
        entrypoint:
            - ./Entrypoint.sh

    webapi:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}webapi
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Source/Code/Web/WebApi/Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            - mssql

    maintenance:
        image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}maintenance
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Source/Code/Web/Maintenance/Dockerfile
        depends_on:
            - mssql
```

`DockerScripts\Shell\Entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

# Start SQL server
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr

# Wait for MSSQL server to start
export STATUS=1
i=0
while [[ $STATUS -ne 0 ]] && [[ $i -lt 30 ]]; do
    i=$i+1
    /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -t 1 -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -Q "select 1" >> /dev/null
    STATUS=$?
done

if [ $STATUS -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Error: MS SQL Server took more than 30 seconds to start up."
    exit 1
fi

echo "MS SQL Server started successfully."

echo "Setting up server login."

/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd  -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -S localhost -i CreateLogin.sql
```

`DockerScripts\SQL\CreateLogin.sql`

```
USE [master];
GO
CREATE LOGIN [$(LOGIN)] WITH PASSWORD=N'$(PASSWORD)', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF;
GO
ALTER SERVER ROLE [dbcreator] ADD MEMBER [$(LOGIN)];
GO
```

---

#### UPDATE

I removed a lot of stuff since it doesn't relate to the issue.
So for now, the main problem persists - `Entrypoint.sh` just not being called on compose startup.

Comment: You can add a sleep 1 in the while loop waiting for sql server start

Comment: @PtitXav It is not solving my problem, but thank you anyway, I forgot to put `sleep` there.

Comment: maybe exec inside once and try to use sqlcmd manually to see what is the issue.

Comment: @TheFool, sorry, didn't really get what you mean. I understand your idea but didn't get how you want me to do that. Could you explain in more detail, please?

Comment: hard to say exactly because you have posted too much sutff imo. Its not very focused. But I am suggesting to you use [exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) on the running container using bash or sh as command and providing the -ti flags. Or that you use docker-compose [run](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) on the service to do the same. Once inside you can start debugging by using sqlcmd.

Comment: @TheFool, thanks, I'll try at the nearest time.

Comment: Did you get any of the output you have in EntryPoint.sh ? If you start sqlserver or any process in a docker then all created process/data will be deleted when docker process ends.

Comment: @TheFool Okay, so I did small research as you advised and discovered one typo in my `CreateLogin.sql` - the `$LOGIN` placeholder was missing round brackets, so once I changed it to `$(LOGIN)` - it started to be replaced with environment variable as it should. BUT, this only happens when I manually execute my `Entrypoint.sh`, otherwise it is not being called at all.

Comment: @TheFool, so now we know, that all scripts are ok, but `Entrypoint.sh` is not being executed automatically on startup. Do you have any idea what may cause such behavior? Thanks :)

Comment: put a `set -e` at the top of your entrypoint and try to execute the whole script by hand from inside the container. Check the with `$?` is the return code is non 0.

Comment: Although, you already said you did execute it manually, and it worked. That's strange. Then it also should work on startup.

Comment: @TheFool, I guess it will work if it would be called on startup :) I also checked if the script has required permissions with `ls -lt ./Entrypoint.sh` and received this output `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1097 Nov 17 18:00 Entrypoint.sh` where `x` in the beginning stands for execute permission, I guess.

Comment: Docker itself would show you an error and immediately exit the container if it couldn't find or execute the script, AFAIK.

Comment: What is the current workdir when you go inside the container? Since you mount the script to the root path `/`. It could only work if the workdir inside the container is also `/` since you use as entrypoint a relative path. `./script`. In any case, it would be more solid to make it absolute and use `/script`.

Comment: @TheFool workdir was root, and no surprise - when I moved scripts to a separate folder and set it as workdir - nothing changed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so finally I was able to solve this issue.

The problem was not that `Entrypoint.sh` was not called, but that all the commands after

```
# Start SQL server
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

were just skipped.

I don't really know why, but I was searching the web more and more and in the end, I came up with this solution.

First of all, I separated the login creation logic into its own script file, this slightly improves readability:

`DockerScripts/Shell/CreateLogin.sh`

```
#!bin/bash

echo "Creating MS SQL Login."

for i in {1..50};
do

/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U sa -P $SA_PASSWORD -S localhost -i CreateLogin.sql

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "MS SQL Login created."
        break
    else
        echo "..."
        sleep 1
    fi

done
```

Secondly - I simplified my `Entrypoint.sh` file to just a few rows:

```
#!bin/bash
/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr | /opt/mssql/bin/permissions_check.sh | /Scripts/CreateLogin.sh
```

Let me explain what the commands above means:

- `/opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr` - this start the server itself.
- `/opt/mssql/bin/permissions_check.sh` - this is just the default
  entrypint file.
- `/Scripts/CreateLogin.sh` - and this point us to the
  server login creation.

And of course, I mounted the new shell script to a volume.

That's it, literally months of struggling with this issue, and turned out it was very simple to solve.

Hope this would help somebody else. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. It helps me a lot! The only problem I have is that I keep incurring this error (my script is very similar to yours): WARNING: Connection error: The port number 1433/database is not valid.

Comment: @bellotto, Glad my answer helped you as well :) Maybe your 1433 port is already allocated, I don't really know, just a guess... But I have never seen such error before. Sorry, nothing I can do to help you.